# Url title namespacing problem

Tags: channel-entries, category-archive

I have this code

```
{exp:channel:entries
        channel="xxxxxx"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
        entry_id="{segment_2}"
        status="open|closed"
        track_views="one"
    }
        {url_title}

        {exp:channel:category_archive
            channel="yyy"
            style="linear"
        }
            {categories}
                {entry_titles}
                    {url_title}                                                     
                {/entry_titles}
            {/categories}
        {/exp:channel:category_archive}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Apparently, EE doesn’t know how to distinguish between the {url_title} of channel entries and category archive since it shows value of the channel entries {url_title} even inside the category archive tags.

I really think that EE should be able to namespace variables properly or at least provide some alternative names to avoid name conflicts like this.

But for now, is there a way to circumvent this?

**EDIT:**

- The channel in the category_archive `yyy` is a relationship field
- What I am trying to do here is to show `yyy` selected items grouped by category

Comment: Have you tried using {entry_titles:url_title}?

Answer (score 1):

Until {entry_titles} gets its own dedicated {entry_url_title} (if ever) this is a typical situation where you could use an embed for the nested category_archive tag.

However, if yyy is already a relationship field, i wonder if there isn't a different approach to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [VMG Nested](https://github.com/vector/VMG-Nested) add-on to prefix the variables on the category_archive tag. It's designed for nesting multiple instances of the same tag, but will also work for helping to namespace different tags with overlapping variables.